# PHP & MySQL - How to delete a users records from two tables

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Hello I'm new to PHP & MySQL and I was wondering how can I delete all of `user_id 3` records from these two tables below using PHP & MySQL?

My MySQL tables

```
CREATE TABLE ls (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
skill VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
experience VARCHAR(22) DEFAULT NULL,
self_grade VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
date_updated DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);


CREATE TABLE us (
id INT(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
skill_id INT(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
user_id INT(13) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

us table values

```
id  skill_id    user_id
9   7           3
10  8           3
11  9           3
12  10          3
13  17          6
```

ls table values

```
id  skill   experience      self_grade  date_created            date_updated
7   html    5 years         A           2010-10-19 07:11:08     2010-10-19 07:12:06
8   jquery  10 years        B           2010-10-19 07:11:27     2010-10-19 07:12:06
9   css     1 year          NULL        2010-10-19 07:11:38     2010-10-19 07:12:06
10  php     2 years         C           2010-10-19 07:13:05     NULL
17  php     2 years         C           2010-10-19 07:19:05     NULL
```

Comment: Seriously? You never considered just using a couple `DELETE` statements?

Comment: @Slokun Seriously why did u leave an unhelpful comment seriously?

Comment: @noob because this just seems like the sort of thing you could have solved yourself with a simple Google search for "MySQL delete two tables"

Comment: @Slokun Seriously what's with everybody and google, this still does not justify your comment seriously.

Comment: @noob Because people tend to like it if you show you've put effort into trying to solve it yourself, such as doing some reading on related topics, or what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Slokun you assume too soon seriously which makes you look like well I'll end it there seriously.

Answer (score 2):

You could fetch all rows belonging to `user_id = 3` and then build a `DELETE` statement with a generated `WHERE` clause.

But, however, I'm wondering if you have an inappropriate table design as you have a m:n relation between user and skill and you want to delete all skills the user with id 3 is related with. But this implicates a 1:m relation between user and skill (1 user has multiple skills, not sharing the skills with others). Or maybe I got something wrong...?

Comment: How are my tables inappropriate? The user is not sharing the skills.

Comment: Sorry in advance, if I got something wrong. But you have a "connecting" table (us) relating users and skills. This implicates a m:n relation between user and skill, meaning that many users may have the same skill (and, off course, vice versa). But, as I supposed and you confirmed, you would like to have a 1:m relation between user and skill: One user may have multiple skills; every skill belongs to one and only one user. So, I need only 2 tables instead of 3. The user table and the skill table holding a foreign key user_id.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use a multi-table DELETE statement, eg.

```
DELETE FROM ls, us USING ls
    JOIN us ON us.skill_id = ls.id
WHERE ls.user_id = 3
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL does support multi-table deletions, use:

```
DELETE a, b
  FROM ls a 
  JOIN us b ON b.skill_id = a.id
 WHERE b.user_id = 3
```